# how can i use rawquery in thingengineer returning limited numbers of row example 5

Tags: sql

this is my rawQuery

```
$users = $this->db->rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM `tbl_emp_information` WHERE first_name = '$name' OR last_name = '$name' OR middle_name = '$name' ",2
    );
```

i thought it will work but not,
i get the idea in this code

```
$users = $db->get('users'); //contains an Array of all users 
$users = $db->get('users', 10); //contains an Array 10 users
```